# Using template string as Vue template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am in the process of learning Vue. As far as I know I should be able to use a simple template string as a template in Vue. But for some reason, Vue renders only the first html tag.

```js
Vue.config.devtools = true;

let template = `<h2>Hi {{name}}</h2><h1>{{age}}</h1>`

const vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            name: 'Name',
            age: 23,
            message: 'hello'
        }
    },
    template,
    methods: {
        greet(e) {
            return this.message = e.target.value
        },
        esc(e) {
            e.target.value = ''
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

This renders only "Hi Name". Why isn't age showing up?

Comment: Side note: It's a "template" (or "template literal"), not a "template string". If it's untagged, it *evaluates* to a string, but if it's used with a tag function, it doesn't necessarily.

Comment: Nice one including the snippet!! Just FYI, the HTML pane in Stack Snippets is automatically put inside a `body` element, so you don't include `html`, `head`, or `body` there. I've updated the snippet to fix that. More about creating snippets: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/

Answer (score 3):

Vue templates should have only one root node. I think you should have a message in your console warning about that.

Try:

```
let template = `<div><h2>Hi {{name}}</h2><h1>{{age}}</h1></div>`
```

Answer (score 1):

After search a lot ways to implement component template even this one - all searchers need to know it must chance this flag to true - and add 10Kb to final result hahaha - this little one will add the compiler to properly do work - by default its false

// if you are using VUE -> vue.config.js
module.exports = {
runtimeCompiler: true
};

// if you are using VUE+QUASAR -> quasar.config.js
add at -> build: { vueCompiler: true, }

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues:

1. As [Sergeon said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55100633/157247), there must be one root node, not two.
2. Vue's templates are *different* from JavaScript's template literals. You've used Vue's syntax (`{{name}}`), but in a JavaScript template literal. You probably wanted a simple string. (Although you could certainly use an untagged template literal instead if you wanted, since they evaluate to strings. Just not that `{{name}}` and such placeholders are handled by Vue, and `${name}` and such will be handled by the JavaScript template itself.)

Fixing those, it seems to work:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = true;

let template = "<div><h2>Hi {{name}}</h2><h1>{{age}}</h1></div>";

const vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            name: 'Name',
            age: 23,
            message: 'hello'
        }
    },
    template,
    methods: {
        greet(e) {
            return this.message = e.target.value
        },
        esc(e) {
            e.target.value = ''
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```